# How to make Internet Explorer display .PNG image if its URL is specified without .PNG extension?

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer

For example, I wish `IE` could display png image, represented by URL
"http://update1.osmp.ru/logos/7642909813539583507":

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Failed to display png image that comes without .png extension in URL</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://update1.osmp.ru/logos/7642909813539583507">
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work because http://update1.osmp.ru/logos/7642909813539583507 is not resolved as PNG file by `IE`. Is there any workaround, plug-in, whatever to display such a url resource in `IE` using `img` tag?

Comment: my chrome also does not recognize it

Comment: I haven't noticed any issues neither with chrome nor firefox.
Both browsers are rendering html page along with successfully loaded png image.

Comment: but if you load the second link http://update1.osmp.ru/logos/7642909813539583507 in Chrome it renders the text only

Comment: yes you're right. But I do care about using that link with img tag in html rather than opening bare link in browser. Try to open html that I posted,  with Chrome and IE. You'll feel the difference.

Comment: I would try to but there is no fiddle... Anyway you already have two answers and you should choose any as a correct one

Answer (score 4):

There's no such thing as a file extension in a URL. Just things that look like file extensions and might happen to map on to a file with one on the file system.

It is the content type that determines how an HTTP resource will be handled, and if you examine that one…

> ```
> [ david ][ david@raston ] %  lynx -dump -head "http://update1.osmp.ru/logos/7642909813539583507"
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Wed, 07 Oct 2015 09:24:16 GMT
> Content-Type: text/plain
> ```

… you'll see that the server claims it is a plain text file and not a PNG image (`image/png`).

You need to fix the server so it sends the correct content type.

How you do this will depend on the server and any server side software you are using to generate the image.

For instance, if you are serving up a static file which doesn't have a file extension (servers normally use the file extension on the file system to determine the content type for static files) and you are using Apache HTTPD, then you could use [the `ForceType` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#forcetype).

e.g. in your server configuration:

```
<Location /logos/>
    ForceType image/png
</Location>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The big problem is I don't control the server. I'm just a client.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `Content-Type` header of your response. It is `text/plain`, but it must be `image/png`.

The `Content-type` is set by the server that return the image. You should have a look at your server configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The big problem is I don't control the server. I'm just a client.

Comment: Did you find the solution @DmitryShebeko? I am stuck on a similar issue with my windows app throwing 'DOM7009: Unable to decode URL error'. Thanks