# Internet Explorer does not display images - Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, internet-explorer

In my application I am displaying images. In Chrome, Firefox and Safari everything works fine. If I am using Internet Explorer I get this: [As Internet Explorer displays the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXdpu.png)

I already tried to set the ContentType and ContentLength in the Http response:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/picture-details/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getImages(@PathVariable final String id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setContentType(String.valueOf(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG));
    response.setContentLength(b.getDatei().length);
    response.setContentType("image/jpg");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);


    return b.getDatei();
}
```

My HTML Code looks like this:

```
<img th:src="@{/picture-details/}+${bild.id}" auto-height"id="auto-height" alt='Detail Bild'/>
```

I also found this [Image without extension in src not loading in IE alone, and works perfect in all other browers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052184/image-without-extension-in-src-not-loading-in-ie-alone-and-works-perfect-in-all) but unfortunately nothing helped.

Comment: IE is a fickle thing. Try to open a developer tools panel and click on the console tab. Messages there might give you some clue what's wrong.

Comment: The problem is, if I open the IE dev tools it crashes :/

Comment: No ideas? No-one with the same problem?

Comment: I would suggest you to start from figuring out why it crashes and then using developer tools investigate the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Select Option A or Option B**

**Option A. Using XML Config**

`<security:headers>`

`<security:content-type-options disabled="true"/>`

`</security:headers>`

**Option B. Using JAVA Config**

```
http
        ...
        .headers()
        .contentTypeOptions().disable()
        ...
```